# What happened to Peter Pettigrew?

Tags: character, harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-1

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part 1*, Harry and company are in Malfoy manner's cellar. Peter Pettigrew walks down and then pretty stupidly walks into the cellar without looking, where he is stunned:

[image: Deathly Hallows Pettigrew Malfoy Manor]
<sup>You know, I forgot how dark this movie was. Literally.</sup>

After that, he just disappears from the movie and doesn't reappear, not even at the Battle of Hogwarts. What happens to him? Did the stunning spell actually kill him somehow? Or did Voldemort just kill him off-screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How Peter died in the book:**

In Deathly Hallows, Harry and Ron are kept as prisoners in the cellar of the Malfoys mansion.

> While Harry and Ron are being kept there, Wormtail/Peter P checks on the prisoners and is attacked. Wormtail begins strangling Harry with the silver hand, but when reminded by Harry that he once saved his life, Wormtail hesitates for a moment. The silver hand turns against him and strangles him to death as punishment for his moment of pity.
>   <sub>(source Wiki)</sub>

They haven't showed it in the movie, but his hesitation to strangling Harry makes his silver hand (the one Voldemort gave him) turn on Peter.

**So basically Peter dies by his own hand.**

In movie, he just fades away without clear idea as to how Peter P died.